# Convert Umbraco site to Plain HTML website

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, umbraco

We have a asp.net mvc website which is using umbraco CMS system. Now,we want to convert the CMS system to plain HTML pages. We do not have the complete code of the website.
How can we remove CMS system and convert it into flat HTML files easily without writing the code from the scratch for this website.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to move away from a CMS? A CMS is build to make things easier and you are moving going back to the dark ages of the internets where we build websites with notepad by typing HTML by hand.

*Discaimer: I am an umbraco dev, and I love the product. So I might be biased*

To answer your question, I use http://www.httrack.com/ to backup existing (old) websites before moving to a new platform & hosting.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

1. For every page, view source and copy the shown Html to a new Html file. Make sure you honour the folder structure too.
2. You could also use https://www.httrack.com/ that might give you what you need.

To try to persuade you not to:

However I would *strongly* recommend against doing this. Umbraco has great mechanisms in place that give almost comparable speed to a flat file website. It uses an Xml file that gets updated when database values are changed, and builds pages and content from this.

If you flatten your website to plain Html files *all* your Urls will invariably change and this is super bad for SEO. You will also have a 'mare of a time trying to update the site with new content or editing the same content found across all pages e.g. the main navigation and footer.